# Rally to Salesforce Integration for Dashboards

Tags: apex, integration, dashboard

We do work on an agile model SFDC project and use Rally as a tool. We would like to have some dashboards in SFDC which can show the status of user stories in Rally. Please let me know if any of you can help me.

Thanks
Nitin

Answer (score 1):

Rally does have a Salesforce connector and you can get information from here [CA Agile Central Support Manager](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-support-manager-salesforcecom)

You can use Salesforce to create user defects and user stories as cases and log them into Rally and keep working on those. When you update those stories in Rally it gets reflected in Salesforce cases.

[image]

I haven't worked on this connector and got all these details from google search.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much  for the answer, Vignesh. Actually I am not looking for this feature. What I am looking for is to create dashboards from the data generated  from rally. For ex, the user stories created in a month and developed successfully

Comment: You can make use of external object in Salesforce to connect with rally and you can get the data. But am not sure whether we can generate reports from external object.